# Will my male cat go looking for my female missing cat?

Tags: cats

I have a male cat and female cat they are both 1yrs old the  female has not come home yet. Will the male cat go looking for her? And bring her home?

Comment: Maybe? And maybe? Depends on the cats involved, whether he finds her, whether she wants to follow him home right now, whether he wants to come home right now, whether either of them can come home from there... I ***REALLY*** wouldn't bet on it being successful.